# background image only appears when content is in div

Tags: html, css

I want my div with a background image to cover the entire browser window. I also have another div with content inside it. When the content in the content div is full of data (i.e fills up the browser window) , the image shows fully. When i emptied the contents of the div, the image was only partially visible (the height of the content div). As content was added to the content div, more of the image appears. Heres the html:

```
 <div class="whole">
 <div class="content"> 
    <p>the more content in here, the more of the image is shown</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Here's the css:

```
 .whole {
 background: url(tree.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
height:100%;
  }

 .content {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 40px auto;
background: rgba(22,22,22, 0.5);
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
border-radius: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 32px;

}
```

How do i make the image in the div with the whole class take up the entire browser window regardless of how much content is in the content div? Thanks

Comment: background-image is shown when the element has height and width, since there's no content, there's no height. You can either specify the height/width manually or use the min-height min-width property depending on the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width and height of html,

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.whole {
  background: url(http://wac.2f9ad.chicdn.net/802F9AD/u/joyent.wme/public/wme/assets/ec050984-7b81-11e6-96e0-8905cd656caf.jpg?v=55) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="content">
    <p>the more content in here, the more of the image is shown</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Hash..i knew it was a simple solution.